# Calculating work done by buoyant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Consider a block of size $h\times h\times h$.(Base area=$A$=$h^2$, density=$\rho$). It is kept  with half it's height submerged in a tank that is filled with a liquid (density=$2\rho$ with base area= $2A$. We are applying a force $F$ to *slowly* submerge it completely.

**Question**

Find the work done by the Buoyant force, Gravity and the force $F$ in the process.

**My attempt**:

*Work done by gravity*

If we displace the block by $x$ and the rise in water level is $y$, we have $A(x+y)=2A(y)$, since the volume of water is constant. We thus get $x=y$. Therefore, we only need to "push" the block by a distance $h/4$.(i.e, the center of mass is displaced by $h/4$ in the process). Work by gravity= $mgh/4$=$\rho Agh^2/4$, which is correct.

*Work done by buoyant force*

If we displace the block by $x$, the submerged height becomes $(h/2 + 2x)$. The buoyant force is $(2\rho)(A)(h/2 + 2x)(g)$. If we displace the block by $dx$, then work by buoyant force= $\int^{h/4}_{0}2\rho A(h/2 + 2x)gdx$. This comes out to be $3\rho Agh^2/8$. However, the correct answer is $3\rho Agh^2/4$.

**potential reason for being off by a factor of $1/2$**: The point of application of the bouyant force is the center of the submerged part: it is changing continuously.

Which leads me to my question:

**How do we account for the fact that the point of application of force is changing at every instant, while calculating the work done?**

Comment: Join me here,https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1508/general-chatroomnon-hindi-speakers-come-at-your-own-risk

Answer (score 2):

> The buoyant force is $(2ρ)(A)(h/2+2x)(g)$. If we displace the block by
> $\text{d}x$, then work by buoyant force= $\int_0^{h/4}ρA(h/2+2x)g\text{d}x$. This comes out to
> be $3ρAgh^2/8$. However, the correct answer is $3ρAgh^2/4$.

I've checked all your calculations and reasoning and cannot find fault with them. The tedious integral:

$$\int_0^{h/4}2ρA(h/2+2x)g\text{d}x=\frac{3\rho Agh^2}{8}$$

also computed correctly.

> How do we account for the fact that the point of application of force
> is changing at every instant, while calculating the work done?

We don't have to: the integral 'does it for us'.

So in the final analysis I believe simply that your textbook is wrong: it wouldn't be the first or last time that happened!

Comment: A nice check would be to see that the work done by gravity and the force F should sum to the change in potential energy of the system

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: But we also need to take into account the rise in potential energy of the rising water.